# Discord.py: discord.utils has no attribute 'format_dt'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

So the title says it all. I've also tried updating Discord.py with the following code:

```py
import discord, os, discord.ext
import discord_components as dcomponents
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, Select, SelectOption
from discord.ext import commands
def vcheck():
  if discord.__version__ != "2.0.0a":
    try:
      printf('DISCORD UPDATE DETECTED. Installing...', 'red')
      result, ver = [], discord.__version__;
      result.append(os.system('pip install --upgrade pip'))
      result.append(os.system('pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py'))
      printf('Succesfully installed version {}! Old version: {}.\nInstall results: {}'.format(discord.__version__, ver, result), 'green')
      del ver
    except (BaseException, Exception) as exc:
      printf(repr(exc), 'red')
      pass
  if discord.__version__ != "2.0.0a": vcheck();
vcheck() # loops indefinitely and it won't run until Discord's version is 2.0.0a.
```

When `vcheck()` is called, it would loop indefinitely and it wouldn't run until Discord's version is 2.0.0a. **(It does not either update at all).** Any fix for this?

> **Is this question duplicated?** No. I have reviewed that there are no questions with this exact title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it looks like the problem is an old version of `discord.py`

I'd recommend first not using actual Python code to update it. If you can, try using the command line tool `pip` to update.
Here are a few methods you can try.

## Upgrading using `pip`

Run
`pip install --upgrade discord`
and
`pip install --upgrade discord.py`

## Reinstalling

Run
`pip uninstall discord`
and
`pip uninstall discord.py`

Those commands uninstall `discord.py`

Then run
`pip install discord`
and
`pip install discord.py`

These steps will reinstall `discord.py`.

Using the command line version of `pip` will probably work better than installing using code.
Please tell me whether or not this works.

Note: `discord.py` is [going to be deprecated](https://gist.github.com/Rapptz/4a2f62751b9600a31a0d3c78100287f1), so you may want to find another library to make a Discord bot.

Answer (score 0):

Heyy, you can use python's official library [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/). Try This once :

```py
import pip 

def upgrade(package):
    if hasattr(pip, 'main'):
        pip.main(['install', '--upgrade', package])
    else:
        pip._internal.main(['install', '--upgrade', package])
```

Comment: Alright, thank you so much for this. I don't have enough reputation, but I will mark this comment as Solution if this works. Once again, thank you so much. <3

Comment: Update: didn't work... Still returns version `1.7.3`, I don't know what to do! D:

Comment: ok i have edited my answer